# How do I write regular expression for multiple occurrences of delimited strings

Tags: python, regex

I can get multiple strings starting with `$startMsg$` and ending with `$endMsg$`. So following are acceptable and unacceptable:

1. `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$`  :  Allowed
2. `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$aaa`  :  Not allowed as there is `aaa` after $endMsg$
3. Expecting $startMsg$, but found only $endMsg$.
   `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$endMsg$`  :  Not allowed
4. No matching $endMsg$ found.
   `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$startMsg$`  :  Not allowed
5. `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$startMsg$dad$endMsg$`  :  Allowed
6. $endMsg$ found before $startMsg$.
   `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$endMsg$dad$startMsg$`  :  Not allowed
7. aaa`$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$`  :  Not allowed, as there is `aaa` before `$startMsg$`

I tried something like this:

```
 ^((\$startMsg\$[^(\$startMsg\$>>)(\$endMsg\$)]*\$endMsg\$))*$
```

I can get multiple strings starting with `$startMsg$` and ending with `$endMsg$`. So following are acceptable and unacceptable:

1. `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$`  :  Allowed
2. `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$aaa`  :  Not allowed as there is `aaa` after $endMsg$
3. Expecting $startMsg$, but found only $endMsg$.
   `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$endMsg$`  :  Not allowed
4. No matching $endMsg$ found.
   `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$startMsg$`  :  Not allowed
5. `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$startMsg$dad$endMsg$`  :  Allowed
6. $endMsg$ found before $startMsg$.
   `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$xyz$endMsg$dad$startMsg$`  :  Not allowed
7. aaa`$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$`  :  Not allowed, as there is `aaa` before `$startMsg$`

I tried something like this:

```
 ^((\$startMsg\$[^(\$startMsg\$>>)(\$endMsg\$)]*\$endMsg\$))*$
```

- `^` at start: start of the string
- `\$`: escaping `$`
- `$` at end: end of the string

But it seems gross incorrect.

But it seems gross incorrect. How I do this in python?

Is `[^(\$startMsg\$>>)(\$endMsg\$)]*` allowed to match any string not containing `$startMsg$` and `$endMsg$`. Seems that, plain no? But then how I am supposed to do this without complecating regex?

Or this is simply undoable with regex as its related to pushdown automata and hence absolutely undoable with finite automate / regex.

Comment: Do you know about https://regex101.com/?

Comment: yup, tried already

Comment: I suspect there should be a solution other than regex. [The "generic" regex](https://regex101.com/r/0avtJO/1) looks too cumbersome.

Comment: Do you actually need a regex? Why don't you use ``str.split``, ``str.find` and similar methods? Do you want to *parse* or just *validate* the messages?

Comment: I wanted to get string between `$startMsg$` and `$endMsg$` pairs

Answer (score 2):

Check this regex which works fine for the examples you mentioned.

```
^(\$startMsg\$)((\w)*(\$endMsg\$\w+\$startMsg\$)*(\w)*)*(\$endMsg\$)$
```

Change **\w** if you have anything else between start and end other than characters.

And then if you just want to grab the characters in between the start and end of strings apply following regex on top

```
(?<=\$startMsg\$)\w+(?=\$endMsg\$)
```

This will list give you the characters.

Comment: Seems to work on examples in the question, but fails if there are no characters between an `$endMsg$` and the subsequent `$startMsg$`, as in `$startMsg$abcd$endMsg$$startMsg$dad$endMsg$`. The original question doesn't address this case, so the answer isn't wrong, but maybe this should be addressed.

Comment: Make **\w** 0 or more characters instead of 1 or more in that case. Like this : 
    ^(\$startMsg\$)((\w)*(\$endMsg\$\w*\$startMsg\$)*(\w)*)*(\$endMsg\$)$

Comment: Ohhh, just realized that the presumption you inferred from examples I gave is incorrect. There can be anything between `$startMsg$` and $endMsg$ flags except those flags. Not just `(\w)*`.

Comment: As I commented in the answer, you can change \w to anything you have between those strings. If it is literally anything then use `.*` otherwise, pick the fillers based on the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

[If you really want to use regex](https://regex101.com/r/O0JILY/1)

```
^((\$startMsg\$)[^$]*?(\$endMsg\$)(([^$]*?)(?=\$startMsg\$)|.{0}))*?$
```

Unfortunately you can't use `[]` constructs with a sequence of characters, only individual characters. So, instead you can use LookAhead/LookBehind (`(?=...)` and `(?<=...` respectivly) with a lazy quantifier to match everything until that sequence, as I did with `([^$]*?)(?=\$startMsg\$)`.

I should mention though, there absolutely are other ways of doing which are far more readable than this hot mess. Regex is cool, but complex sequences like this are confusing and hard to understand, and should be avoided when ever possible.